# How to generate google access token using cronjob?

Tags: php, google-api, cron, google-oauth

I have Generated Access token using this script

Here's code

```
$OAuth = array(
    'oauth_uri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    'client_id' => '',
    'client_secret' => '',
    'access_type' => 'online',
    'redirect_uri' => '',   uri()
    'oauth_token_uri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
);
$token = array(
    'access_token' => '',
    'token_type' => '',
    'expires_in' => '',
    'refresh_token' => ''
);
$title = 'No Code';
$AuthCode = 'Null';

$error = _get_url_param($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'error');
if ($error != NULL)
{   $title = $error;
}
else
{   
    $AuthCode = _get_url_param($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'code');
    if ($AuthCode == NULL)
    {   
        $OAuth_request = _formatOAuthReq($OAuth, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing");
        header('Location: ' . $OAuth_request);
        exit; 
    }
    else
    {
        $title = 'Got Authorization Code';
        $token_response = _get_auth_token($OAuth, $AuthCode);
        $json_obj = json_decode($token_response);
        $token['access_token'] = $json_obj->access_token;
        $token['token_type'] = $json_obj->token_type;
        $token['expires_in'] = $json_obj->expires_in;
        $token['refresh_token'] = $json_obj->refresh_token;
        echo 'access_token = ' . $json_obj->access_token;
    }
}
function _get_auth_token($params, $code)
{
    $url = $params['oauth_token_uri'];
    $fields = array(
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => $params['client_id'],
        'client_secret' => $params['client_secret'],
        'redirect_uri' => $params['redirect_uri'],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
    );
    $response = _do_post($url, $fields);
    return $response;
}
function _formatOAuthReq($OAuthParams, $scope)
{
    $uri = $OAuthParams['oauth_uri'];
    $uri .= "?client_id=" . $OAuthParams['client_id'];
    $uri .= "&redirect_uri=" . $OAuthParams['redirect_uri'];
    $uri .= "&scope=" . $scope;
    $uri .= "&response_type=code";
    $uri .= "&access_type=offline";
    return $uri;
}
```

When I run the script in Chrome Browser it works.

But when I set a cronjob but it's not working, and no token is generated

How to generate google access token using cronjob?

I hope you people understand it and can help me :).

Comment: _Of course_ this doesn’t work as a cronjob - please don’t say you are actually surprised by that? The OAuth authentication flow is based on _user interaction_ - the redirect to the login URL has to happen inside the user’s _browser_, because that is where they are logged into Google in the first place. No one on your server is logged into Google, and there is probably no one who would follow that redirect either.

Comment: When you write header un php you are sending a http response to your browser. Thats not works in a command line interface environment. May be you can simulate the login with scrapping methods...but...It not Will be easy. I dont know if Google offers any method for login without browser interaction...probably no.